# Why does the each() end after it goes through array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, each

I have this script below and I want it to loop through each anchor and give the background

```
$c = ['85CC4C', 'D1FFCD', 'FF8D9D', '8A5949', 'CC8066'];
$('a').each(function(i){
$(this).css({'background':'#'+$c[i], 'color':getTintedColor($c[i], -55)});
});
```

Why does it stop after it goes through the array colors? I want it to repeat the 5 colors.

Comment: You're not looping through the `array`, you are looping through all of the `a` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it stop after it goes through the array colors?

Because `$c[i]` then yields `undefined`, instead of starting the index over from zero. You can use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) to do so:

```
$('a').each(function(i){
    var col = $c[i % $c.length];
    $(this).css({
        background: '#'+col,
        color: getTintedColor(col, -55)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cycle through the colors, try `$c[i % 5]` instead of `$c[i]`:

```
$c = ['85CC4C', 'D1FFCD', 'FF8D9D', '8A5949', 'CC8066'];
$('a').each(function(i){
    $(this).css({'background':'#'+$c[i % 5], 'color':getTintedColor($c[i % 5], -55)});
});
```

Inside the `each()` loop, the `i` variable is the index of each anchor tag. Your color array, though, has only 5 colors. Using `i % 5` will always give a number between `0` and `4`, thus always a valid index in the color array.

Answer (score 0):

Cause if `i`  value is greater than length of the array , **$c[i] is undefined**..

Array has 5 items and you are trying to assign the `anchor` a 6 item value.

So you need to reset the value when length is greater than the array (need to use modulo operator) . Something like this

```
$c = ['85CC4C', 'D1FFCD', 'FF8D9D', '8A5949', 'CC8066'];
$('a').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css({
        'background': '#' + $c[i % $c.length],
        'color': getTintedColor($c[i % $c.length], -55)
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rhTfh/)**